# FileUpload.Hasfile is returning false(What is the reason?)

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have a fileupload control on my .aspx page.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

I am validating my control on my CS page.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
```

but this if condition is returning always false. I am not getting what is the actual reason! Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: did you select a file using Browse? and is that file path visible on the UI?

Comment: Yes the file path visible on UI and I am using Browse, Exactly the same thing!

Comment: is this control in `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: No! it is <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                </td>

Comment: Are you sure there is no `UpdatePanel` in its HTML heirarchy? It may be on the page or on master page.  It may not be an immediate parent like `td`

Comment: I have done this with Updatepanel. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileUpload` control is not compatible with `UpdatePanel`.  You have two options

1. Move the control outside of `UpdatePanel`
2. If not possible, add a `PostBackTrigger` on the `UpdatePanel`

An example

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="yourButtonIdThatSubmitsFile" />
</Triggers>
```

For more information, you can refer to http://forums.asp.net/t/1142794.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have put my FileUpload Control into a Updatepanel. Then apply a trigger on those buttons from where data is submitting.

```
 <td>
      <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanel1">
          <Triggers><asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsubNxtClm" /></Triggers>
          <Triggers><asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnsubmit" /></Triggers>
          <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
          </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
```